# My system is slow, but can I run Blender better anyway?

Tags: system

this is my computer's system, I'm trying to use Blender 2.78, but it works so slow. Is there anything I can do about it?
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question, add more information and use the tool provide to upload images.

Comment: You need to keep your expectations to a realistic level. If you are just starting to use blender and want to learn, you might not need a powerful computer. Do you really need to use 2.78? Can you use older versions? If you need the newer and more computationally intensive options consider upgrading your hardware.  Else, be happy, learn get good at it, make lots of money and get the newest, shiniest, and most superpowerful of computers.

Comment: Thank you, man. i have already tried a bit older versions, but as they didn't work out either, i thought, problem isn't coming from choosing new version :) Now i'm downloading versions)))

Answer (score 1):

Keep your expectations within reason and consider how much you are willing to commit to a hardware upgrade should you do so. Computer parts aren't necessarily cheap, so be sure to weigh the costa vs. benefits of a potential upgrade before diving headfirst into this. That said, here is some information about upgrading hardware.

3GB of RAM is limited with today's memory-hungry applications. Upgrading to 8GB or even 16GB won't magically turn your PC into a render powerhouse, but it is definitely a start. 
Almost all RAM sticks are fairly simple to swap out, and shouldn't require too much technical know-how. However it is essential that you choose the correct type of RAM stick, else it will not fit onto your motherboard. If you're really unsure, take the PC to a local shop. Other upgrades, such as a CPU, are beyond the scope of this answer.

As for other tips to help performance, quit all nonessential applications when running Blender, and keep your CPU from running hot by ensuring the computer has substantial airflow i.e, keep it in an open area at room temperature and make sure the fans are operational.

Best of luck.